# Changing youtube video playback speed in android

Tags: android, video, youtube-api

I am using YouTubeAndroidPlayer api for playing videos.
And iam able to play videos succesfully in android devices,but not able to change playback speed of videos.
 i am using code below to play video from youtube

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO);

    }
}
```

anybody know how to change playback speed of videos using this api or with any other apis.

Comment: It depends on your Internet speed!! How one can change that??\

Comment: Thanks for your replay,is it possible to change speed for offline videos? .if yes please guide me to do that..

Comment: anyone find solution ?

Comment: No, I cant find any solution :(